# ExpiresDefault on dynamic url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have different types of dynamic urls like
    /dynamic/image/day/blah/blah/blah.jpg
    /dynamic/image/week/blah/blah/blah.png
    /dynamic/image/month/blah/blah/blah.gif

this urls are not actual filesystem paths but served by a php script ..

IN httpd.conf :

whey I try with the following configuration :

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiredDefault A0

<LocationMatch */image/day/*>
ExpiresDefault A86400
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch */image/week/*>
ExpiresDefault A604800
</LocationMatch>
```

It applies last one 'A604800'(after week) expiry header to both type of files .. means even for /day/ type of urls the last ExpiresDefault is overriding to all the above ExpiresDefault .

```
I have also tried putting FilesMatch inside LocationMatch like this :
<LocationMatch */image/week/*>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)">
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>
</LocationMatch>
```

But now not a single directing inside FilesMatch is executing meanse Expires header is not set ..

I have also tried using Header set ,, but looks like it doesn't follow Locationmatch condition but just last Header Set whould apply to all ..

Those are dynamic url , not actual directories , so I can't use different htaccess for different day,week etc ..
Any Solution ..?

Comment: try `<LocationMatch /.*/image/week/.*>`

Comment: It is not regex matching issue thre ... alredy tried almost everything including .*/day/.*  but if those regex are not matching or  matching than why the last ExpiredDefault is being applied on every type of url ?

Comment: run your apache at LogLevel debug you can see exactly what is happening

Comment: Yes there is something . 
Expires_module - server cannot append header after http headers has been sent .

Comment: did u google the error

Comment: I know what that error means , but in this case could'nt understand where I just loading images how headers are already sent .

Comment: May be the htaccess which is responsible to point url to php script is calling first before this directives ?

Comment: can this code be put into htaccess ?

Comment: no u can't only in the config and Virtual Host